# Eliminating left recursion from function call parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, recursive-descent, left-recursion

First of all, I know there are a lot of answers and resources already available regarding this topic. However, I'm having a really hard time understanding the grammar notation that is often used in these answers. So I was hoping someone could explain it in a more intuitive way.

I'm trying to write a simple recursive descent parser for some kind of C-type language. However, I am running into some issues when implementing a function call.

I am trying to support the following syntax:

```
a(b)
a(b, c)
a(b, c)()
a(b, c)(d)
```

Like I said, I have a hard time understanding the grammar notation often used, so I will show my implementation:

```
const functionCall = new Expression((parser) => {
    parser.expect(expression)
    parser.expect('(')
    if (parser.optional(expression)) {
        while (true) {
            if (parser.optional(',')) {
                parser.expect(expression)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    parser.expect(')')    
})

const expression = new Expression((parser) => {
    parser.either([functionCall, literal])
})

const literal = new Expression((parser) => {
    parser.either([{name: 'string_literal'}, {name: 'number_literal'}, {name: 'identifier'}])
})
```

As I understand my grammar is (indirectly?) left recursive because the first thing that can be matched in a function call, can be a function call. If this assumption is right, I wouldn't know how to eliminate this recursion.

Comment: How do you do (repeated) addition? It's not that different.

Comment: @rici I gues i would run in to same issues indeed. I am not very familiar with parsing. I've read some articles on recursive descent, but cant figure out how to solve problems like these.

Comment: In the [example code for a rd parser in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser#C_implementation), note the `while` loops in `term` and `expression`.